# How to get a nested data in faunadb?

Tags: faunadb

In my html/js file I have code like this:

```
adminClient.query(
      q.Get(q.Ref(q.Collection('Todo'), '276653641074475527'))
    )
    .then((ret) => console.log(ret));
```

which is returning output like

[image]

Is there any way to get a cleaned json response without these ts, ref and actual data wrapped in data, so in short I want output like

```
{
    completed: true,
    title: "Build an awesome app!",
    List: {
        title: "Development"
    }
}
```

Note: List is also resolved into its actual value instead of the Ref object.

Here is the schema I used to create the db

```
type Todo {
  title: String!
  completed: Boolean!
  list: List
}

type List {
  title: String!
  todos: [Todo] @relation
}

type Query {
  allTodos: [Todo!]
  todosByCompletedFlag(completed: Boolean!): [Todo!]
  allLists: [List!]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Select()** to extract the field:

```
Select(['data'],Get(Ref(Collection('Todo'), '276653641074475527')))
```